# Enabling compute engine failing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created new project and then went to `VM Instances`, it says enabling compute engine, after some time it throws error `Unknown Exception with Code: 13`. Do I have to set up permissions or anything else?

Comment: There is a similar issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086454/unknown-exception-with-code-13
Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check your billing/payment method. GCE needs a verified payment method

Answer (score 1):

Please try disabling and then enabling the API via the **[Google SDK](https://cloud.google.com/service-management/enable-disable)** and try accessing again:

```
$ gcloud services disable compute.googleapis.com

$ gcloud services enable compute.googleapis.com
```

Lastly, if one of these commands fail please run placing the correct operation ID obtained from the previous commands:

```
$ gcloud services operations describe [operation ID]
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Disabled by mistake with Terraform and now I'm getting the following error:
```
The operation "operations/acf.p2-245543076501-89576eef-a4b1-40bc-9ecb-5bcd5746b4f8" resulted in a failure "[Error in service 'compute.googleapis.com': The service is currently being deactivated and deactivation must complete before activation can occur.
```

Answer (score -1):

I think such error usually appears when the Compute Engine API (CE API) can't be enabled for some reasons. In your case, it was probably due to the time required to the restoring process or to the new billing association to use the GCP services. However, at this time I can confirm that CE API it's enabled in your project, which means that you can proceed to create instances.