# Unknown Exception with Code: 13

Tags: virtual-machine

I have created a new project, then went to VM Instances. It says "enabling compute engine". After some time, it throws the following error:

```
Unknown Exception with Code: 13.
```

Why am I receiving this error? Do I have to set up permissions or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases that error occurs because your project doesn't have a billing account assigned. You can check if this is your problem in the left menu Billing ->  Manage Billing Accounts from drop down box.